# Set component's props dynamically

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need to set component's props after it is stored in a variable, here is pseudo code:

```
render(){

    let items = [{title:'hello'}, {title:'world'}];
    let component = false;

    switch (id) {
      case 1:
        component = <A />
        break;
      case 2:
        component = <B />
        break;      
    }

    return(
      items.map((item, index)=>{
        return(
          <span>
            {/* SOMETHING LIKE THIS WOULD BE COOL - IS THAT EVEN POSSIBLE*/}
            {component.props.set('title', item.title)}
          </span>11

        )
      })
    )
  }
```

Inside `return` I run a loop where I need to set props for the component that is stored inside a variable.... How to set props for this component which I stored earlier in a variable?

Comment: you cannot change state or prop during render, you can use componentDidUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps for it

Comment: Cloning component here is a bad option because it will affect the performance by creating extra memory for the cloned components. And, after cloning the original components become usless. Again, this is a bad way of implementing.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The proper way is to use React's cloneElement method (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).
You can achieve what you want by doing:

```
<span>
  {
    React.cloneElement(
      component,
      {title: item.title}
    )
  }
</span>
```

Comment: anybody knows how to update the clones elements props from parent once its created??

Answer (score 6):

It can be done by assign not jsx but component reference, then use jsx in looping with using of component from variable. Check my code changes.

```
render(){

let items = [{title:'hello'}, {title:'world'}];
let C = null; //null is more accurate for object variable

switch (id) {
  case 1:
    C = A; //it is component reference, C must be from upper letter
    break;
  case 2:
    C = B; //it is component reference
    break;
  default:
    C = A; //good to have default for wrong ids      
}

return(
  items.map((item, index)=>{
    return(
      <span>
        <C {...item} /> //render component with props
      </span>11

    )
  })
)
}
```

Most important things:

1.`C=A;` we set on variable C reference to target component

2.`<C {...item} />` all properties from item object will be set in child component.

3.It can be used in standard way like: `<C title={item.title} />`

Some working example: https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsikora/jtt91wL3/3/

Comment: When `C` becomes `null`, as I see no `default` case in the `switch` to handle this case, React will throw an error. You can try it!

Comment: @PraneshRavi very funny, and where You see default for false? And what have react to standard switch statement? Yes try it yourself! Question was about how set props to dynamic assigned component, not about default in switch.

Comment: Check code with false with id 3 and the same problem occurse, my change on null are not doing any harm. You comment not have sense You give me -1 because orginal answer had no default in switch. And I have proper reason for downvoting You answer - downvoting my answer without any reason is first, next is that You answer is poor answer.

Comment: Check my snippet. Try to make your code work. When you pass `id="3"`, your code will break

Comment: I repeat again, switch without defaut was in orginal code, it is not part of my answer. Please read my comments, you are arguing about switch statement not about real answer content. I added default to stop this conversation without sens, but it has no meaning for it. And Dude You are very irritating guy. Realy You started this conversation without any reason!

Comment: I completely agree, you answer is based on **dynamic tag name** for react component. I get that. In this case, if you don't add an `default` in your switch, if `id=3`, `C` will be `null`. So, React will throw an error. Did you get it?

Comment: If you're so sure, remove the `default` and try passing `id` as 3. Add a working example.

Comment: With false also would be an error,  I checked it. Good luck!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnqzoa4j/ 

This is your fiddle without `default`. It's not even loading. Open the console and see.

Answer (score 2):

**More Use-cases Example ->** for other people that came here:

A way of dynamically rendering all items from pre-declared array with all components and their props:

```
const items = [{component: Home,props:{ icon: 'fa-home', title: 'Home Page'}},{...}]

<div>
    {
       items.map((item) => {
          let Child = item.component;
          return (<Child {...item.props}/>);
       });
     }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `switch` inside the `map()`. Hope this helps!

```js
class A extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <h1>Inside Component A:{this.props.title}</h1>
  }
}

class B extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <h1>Inside Component B: {this.props.title}</h1>
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component{
  render(){
      let items = [{title:'hello'}, {title:'world'}];
      const finalItems = items.map((item, index) => {
         switch (parseInt(this.props.id)) {
            case 1:
             return <A title={item.title}/>
            case 2:
             return <B title={item.title}/>     
         }
       })

      return(
        <span> {finalItems} </span>
      )
    }
 }
ReactDOM.render(<div>
                  <Parent id="1"/>
                  <Parent id="2"/>
                  <Parent id="3"/>
                </div>,
  document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You don't need to add a `default` case as React will ignore `undefined`, which will be returned to the `map` when the switch case fails.

Comment: Switch by id has no connection with items loop so should be called outside, You are doing the same operation in every loop and this operation should be done only one time. This code gives poor performance and it is bad practice.

Comment: @MaciejSikora Added a working example. Hope this clarifies!