# Outputting an array of react components and having access to parent's "this" using a a prop within child

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

I have an array of components which are all separate views that I am injecting to it's parent via a prop

```
const steps = 
[ <StepOne wizardContext={shippingObj.from} onAction={this.handleFrom}/>,
  <StepTwo wizardContext={shippingObj.to} onAction={this.handleFrom} />,
  <StepThree wizardContext={shippingObj.weight} onAction={this.handleFrom} />,
  <StepFour wizardContext={shippingObj.shippingOption} onAction={this.handleFrom} />,
  <Confirm wizardContext={shippingObj} onAction={this.handleFrom} />
]
<Wizard steps={steps}/>
```

In the Wizard component I'm rendering each step based on the actual step

```
{this.props.steps[this.state.compState]}
```

Also in the wizard component I have a method

```
  handleFrom(val) {
    let state = val.stage,
    key = Object.keys(val)[0];
    this.setState({
      wizardContext: { ...this.state.wizardContext, [key]: val[key]}
    })
  }
```

However onAction is undefined meaning it doesn't have access to "this"

If I include each one of them individually within parent wizard component I do have access to this and it works

```
/*THIS WORKS */
switch (this.state.compState) {
      case 1:
        return <StepOne onAction={this.handleFrom} data={this.state.wizardContext.from} />
      case 2:
        return <StepTwo onAction={this.handleFrom} data={this.state.wizardContext.to} />
      case 3:
        return <StepThree onAction={this.handleFrom} data={this.state.wizardContext} />
      case 4:
        return <StepFour onAction={this.handleFrom} data={this.state.wizardContext.shippingOption} />
      case 5: 
        return <Confirm shippingLabel={this.state.wizardContext} labelkeys={this.shippingKeys} />
    }
```

however I want to decouple the steps from the actual wizard

Is there a way to access this or parent methods from the child if the child is an array of components?  Is there a cleaner way to do this?
the components will render just don't have access to "this" in props
Any constructive feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating your array of `steps` outside of the `Wizard` component, so the `this` context does not point back to the `Wizard` (and therefore does not have the appropriate `handleFrom` method).

You can fix this problem by dynamically injecting the correct `this.handleFrom` method as a prop in the `Wizard`'s `render` method. First, remove the `onAction` prop from your `steps` array:

```
const steps = 
[ <StepOne wizardContext={shippingObj.from} />,
  <StepTwo wizardContext={shippingObj.to} />,
  <StepThree wizardContext={shippingObj.weight} />,
  <StepFour wizardContext={shippingObj.shippingOption} />,
  <Confirm wizardContext={shippingObj} />
]
<Wizard steps={steps}/>
```

Then, replace this line:

```
{this.props.steps[this.state.compState]}
```

with this:

```
{
    React.cloneElement(
      this.props.steps[this.state.compState],
      {onAction: this.handleFrom}
    )
}
```

Make sure you have `this.handleFrom = this.handleFrom.bind(this);` in the `Wizard`'s constructor so you bind the appropriate context.

What's happening here is that the context for the `steps` array has no `this.handleFrom`. So, you inject the `onAction={this.handleFrom}` prop inside the `Wizard` component, where the appropriate context is available. For more information on `cloneElement`, see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192882/set-components-props-dynamically).

Comment: Thanks jdupont for your feedback - I need to update the parent state with data from the child and the handleFrom method needs to be within Wizard I still don't have access to "this" and I have binded it properly

Comment: Would you mind showing the code where you bind the handleFrom method to this?

Comment: within the constructor of Wizard

Comment: this.handleFrom = this.handleFrom.bind(this);

Comment: So just to be clear, the `handleFrom` method lives in the `Wizard` component, and the code snippet where you have `const steps=...<Wizard steps={steps} />` also lives in the `Wizard` component?

Comment: no the steps array is being passed into the wizard component via props

Comment: steps is an array of components

Comment: Oh alright I see. So the problem here is that in the place where you're building that array, the `this` context isn't the `Wizard`'s `this`. Give me a minute to update my answer.

Comment: right how do I get Wizard's "this" I've been searching all day

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect my new understanding of your question. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: ah perfect! didn't know you could use React.cloneElement in that manner have actually never used it - thank you so much - I will check your answer off

Comment: Great to hear. Happy coding!